# LWJGL - Matrix4f not rotating correctly

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, rotation, lwjgl

I use the matrix4f class from opengl to rotate my object around the center..

This is how I do it:

```
pos.m30 = -(getWidth()/2f); 
pos.m31 = +(getHeight()/2f);
pos.m20 = -(getWidth()/2f); 
pos.m21 = -(getHeight()/2f);
pos.m00 = +(getWidth()/2f); 
pos.m01 = -(getHeight()/2f);
pos.m10 = +(getWidth()/2f); 
pos.m11 = +(getHeight()/2f);

rotate(pos); //TODO                                           

//Position                                                      
pos.m30 += phyxBody.getPosition().x;                            
pos.m31 += phyxBody.getPosition().y;                            
pos.m20 += phyxBody.getPosition().x;                            
pos.m21 += phyxBody.getPosition().y;                            
pos.m00 += phyxBody.getPosition().x;                            
pos.m01 += phyxBody.getPosition().y;                            
pos.m10 += phyxBody.getPosition().x;                            
pos.m11 += phyxBody.getPosition().y;
```

Rotate method: the angle is in radians..

```
    pos.rotate(phyxBody.getAngle(),new Vector3f(0f,1f,0));
```

Yet this doesn't rotate the body correctly.. It rotates it around the top left corner instead of around the center..

Comment: Try to apply an appropriate translation (`Matrix4f.translate(Vector3f vec)`) before you apply the rotation, and then translate back. Also, you probably shouldn't be directly manipulating those matrix elements; just use a matrix-matrix multiplication (which is exactly what `Matrix4f.rotate` & `Matrix4f.translate` are doing behind-the-scenes) to apply any  transformations.

Comment: Yeah, what you want here is rotation around the object's center. You need to translate the object so that its center is at the origin, then do your rotation and then translate it back. It's typically: translate (-ObjCenter), rotate (X), translate (+ObjCenter)